# Passing arguments to a js function

Tags: javascript

php file…)

When I hardcode the two arguments, the cMGen works fine.
When I try to put in variables (first_var, second_var) it will not function!!!
Can anybody see the reason way. Is there a special syntax for passing 
arguments in this specific situation?

```
function calculate() {
   var cArray = new Array();
   var cArray = <?php echo json_encode(cMGen("XY1115","2"));?>;
   var cArray = cArray.split(',');
   //etc
}
```

Comment: what's the definition of cMGen function? does it accept arguments?

Comment: Yes, the cMGen function looks like this: <?php function cMGen($var1,$var2) {    ---  }  ?>

Comment: can you share the code for cMGen function?

Comment: you might wanna tag this question with php

Comment: No, I am sorry - this is all my "business logic". In fact, as you can see, the function is a php function called from a JavaScript environment. If it works fine when I use single or double quoted arguments but not when I use variables as arguments. Don't you think the issue is a "passing arguments problem"? I am a novice: could it be related to "by reference"/"by value" passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably due to incorrect scoping. Since you're injecting PHP into your client-side you probably need to either set the variable dynamically into your javascript

or

you need to somehow read the client-side variable back to PHP via a REST call or something so that your PHP can use that when calling cMGen etc.

Comment: Thank you, @schlock. I will try your first proposal. Should I "prefix" the arguments/variables with a $-sign?